# How do I drag a view after it is dragged outside of it's parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to able to drag the black box outside of its orange container and be able to drag it again. The black imageview does not respond to touch when it is outside of the orange box. I can only re-drag the black box if it is dropped somewhere in the orange box.

[Screenshot of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JQp.jpg)

My code is as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <com.example.noname.myapplication.DraggableImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_animation_icon_imageview"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:background="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**DraggableImageView.java**

```
public class DraggableImageView extends ImageView {

    float dX, dY;

    public DraggableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                dX = getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center">




        <launcher.simpleapp.vr.com.draggableimageview.DraggableImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_animation_icon_imageview"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:background="#000000"/>



</LinearLayout>


Draggable ImageView 



import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by cvija on 8/28/2016.
 */
public class DraggableImageView extends ImageView{


        int dX, dY;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

        public DraggableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = dX - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = dY - lParams.topMargin;
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    dX = (int)(getX() - event.getRawX());
                    dY =  (int)( getY() - event.getRawY());
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    animate()
                            .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                            .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                            getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = dX - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = dY - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                    setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

The same is working fine for me
```

Answer (score 0):

That sense your touch will goes in the way of the view group first then you will get the control in your view

So you kept the image view inside the linear layout so that you will have control only inside the linear layout